# Regex to match all strings from multiple lists

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to match all strings from list.

```
import re

brand_list = ['scurfa', 'seagull', 'seagull', 'seiko']

regular_expression = rf"({'|'.join(brand_list)}) ([^\s]+)"

description = """
VINTAGE KING SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion,Manual Winding with mod caseback.Serviced 2019.
Power reserve function at 12; push-pull crown at 4
Seiko NE57 auto movement with power reserve
Multilayered dial with SuperLuminova BG-W9
Testing for a ScURFA 42342
"""

print([" ".join(t) for t in re.findall(regular_expression, soup_content.find('blockquote', { "class": "postcontent restore" }).text, re.IGNORECASE)])
```

I got these

```
['SEIKO 44-9990', 'Seiko NE57', 'ScURFA 42342']
```

But I want to replace `([^\s]+)` with this `({'|'.join(model_list)})` based on this list

```
model_list = ['44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'NE57 auto', '42342 ']
```

So I can get output more like this

```
['SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'Seiko NE57 auto', 'ScURFA 42342']
```

Comment: You want to do this in a second pass over the results of the first?

Comment: Is the space after `42342` intended?

Comment: @wwii prefer one shot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  no, i dont think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it exactly the same as your other regex:

```
regular_expression = rf"({'|'.join(brand_list)}) *({'|'.join(model_list)})?"
```

Output:

```
['SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'Seiko NE57 auto', 'ScURFA 42342']
```

The  `*` in the regex between the two list joins means, that it matches both, with space or without.

## EDIT:

Full code I have used to test:

```
import re

brand_list = ['scurfa', 'seagull', 'seagull', 'seiko']
model_list = ['44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'NE57 auto', '42342']

regular_expression = rf"({'|'.join(brand_list)}) *({'|'.join(model_list)})?"

description = """
VINTAGE KING SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion,Manual Winding with mod caseback.Serviced 2019.
Power reserve function at 12; push-pull crown at 4
Seiko NE57 auto movement with power reserve
Multilayered dial with SuperLuminova BG-W9
Testing for a ScURFA 42342
"""

print([" ".join(t) for t in re.findall(regular_expression, description, re.IGNORECASE)])
```

## EDIT 2:

Added trailing question mark for optional model regex.

Comment: i got this error message, TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: I added the full code I used for testing. Can you confirm the same error with this code?

Comment: by the way can make model_list as optional if not found but brand_list mandatory

Comment: Added trailing question mark to make model part optional (zero or one time occuring regex)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the code using

```
import re
brand_list = ['scurfa', 'seagull', 'seiko']
description = """
VINTAGE KING SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion,Manual Winding with mod caseback.Serviced 2019.
Power reserve function at 12; push-pull crown at 4
Seiko NE57 auto movement with power reserve
Multilayered dial with SuperLuminova BG-W9
Testing for a ScURFA 42342
"""
model_list = ['44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'NE57 auto', '42342']
regular_expression = rf"(?:{'|'.join(brand_list)})(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(model_list)}))?"
print(re.findall(regular_expression, description, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output: `['SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'Seiko NE57 auto', 'ScURFA 42342']`

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/tkuSvX)

The `rf"(?:{'|'.join(brand_list)})(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(model_list)}))?"` part creates a `(?:scurfa|seagull|seiko)(?:\s+(?:44-9990 Gold Medallion|NE57 auto|42342))?` pattern (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/VdVHRi/2)) that matches `scurfa`, `seagull` or `seiko`, then  optionally 1 or more whitespaces, and then `44-9990 Gold Medallion`, `NE57 auto` or `42342`.

You do not need a list comprehension if you use non-capturing groups, use `re.findall(regular_expression, description, re.IGNORECASE)` with the pattern.

To match the phrases as whole words, consider adding word boundaries:

```
regular_expression = rf"\b(?:{'|'.join(brand_list)})(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(model_list)}))?\b"
```